Distance from which a person with a specific diopter can see a 20/20 Snellen Eye examination
I am trying to get the distance from the screen (webcam but it's attached on top) to test if the known diopter is still valid or worse. Considering the height of the standard test is 1.5m in height, how can I calculate the formula so it works on a known resolution screen. Here is an example:
If I have a 1920x1080 resolution on my monitor, how do I calculate the distance at which I see 20/20 with a diopter of -1.
Eye examination standard
So, 20/20 means a person sees all the characters on the 8th line from a distance of 20feet (6m)
20/30 means a person sees all the characters on the 6th line from a distance of 20 feet (6m), but a person with normal vision can see it from 20 feet.
I've tried dividing the real 1.5m height to 6 so it fits in a monitor based on PPI (pixels per inch) and also divided the 6m distance to 6 but the results are not accurate.
I am trying to do the code in python but I need to find the formula first. I have an input for the diopter and when I introduce it I want to be placed at a distance from which I can see the examination properly. From testing myself for a -0.5 diopter I could see an 1080px table from approximately 3m, so the result of the formula for the input of -0.5 should be around that.
